# После передачи ajax(ом) меняется кодировка

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Всем привет.

В общем у меня возникла такая проблема, при передаче через ajax данных в php они приходят уже в перекодированном виде.

Заранее предупреждаю что все файлы у меня в кодировке **UTF-8**!

Код примерно следующий:

```
// javascript
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/comment/ajax/setContent/" + commentElement.id + "/" + value,
    success: function (reply) {

        console.log(reply);

        commentElement.querySelector(".comment-text").innerHTML = "";
        commentElement.querySelector(".comment-text").innerHTML = reply;

        close();
     }
});
```

---

```
// php
public function actionAjaxSetCommentContent($commentId, $content) {

    echo $content;

    Comment::updateComment($commentId, $content);

    return true;
}
```

---

В итоге если в JavaScript(е) я передаю строку `< p>Привет!< /p>` то уже в PHP  когда я получаю эту строку через переменную `$content` она превращается в

> %3Cp%3E%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%3C

---

**Пожалуйста** помогите либо разобраться **почему такой переход происходит**, либо подскажите, **что это за кодировка и как ее на стороне php перегнать обратно** в нормальный вид!

Comment: `echo rawurldecode('%3Cp%3E%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%3C');` -> `<p>Привет<`

Comment: Да это работает спасибо. Вот только можно как то сделать что бы он перекодировал строку полностью а не отрубал ее после слеша < /p>

Comment: Так вы не правильно данные передаете. `url` служит для указание адреса, куда передаем, а для данных есть `data` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: вы немного не понимаете... просто я работаю с патерном mvc там перенаправление на различные страницы происходит через роуты 'comment/ajax/getContent/([0-9]+)'          => 'comment/ajaxGetCommentContent/$1',
'comment/ajax/setContent/([0-9]+)/(.+)'     => 'comment/ajaxSetCommentContent/$1/$2',
'catalog'                                   => 'catalog/index'
 на вроде такого а не обращение к конкретным страницам

Comment: Я смотрю на ваш код js и не вижу передачу данных через элемент `data`, но вижу переменную `value`. От сюда и считаю, что данные вы пытаетесь передать через адресную строку :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете метод POST, а данные передаете в GET параметрах.
Попробуйте так:

```
$.post("/comment/ajax/setContent/","id="+commentElement.id+"&value="+value,     function(reply){
    commentElement.querySelector(".comment-text").innerHTML = "";
    commentElement.querySelector(".comment-text").innerHTML = reply;
    close();        
});
```

а в php уже просто доставайте из массива `$_POST['id']`, `$_POST['value']`